# Duda en esta expresión: Serán nada vs no serán nada

Tags: uso-de-palabras, negación

Me surgió la duda al tratar de escribir lo siguiente:

> Para la historia serán nada

El editor me corrige por:

> Para la historia **no** serán nada

Cuál expresión es correcta y por qué?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doble negativo
Adv. de negación + verbo + indefinido:

- **No** serán **nada** = X won't be anything.
- **No** fue **nada** premeditado = Nothing was calculated.
- **No** fue **nada**, en serio = It wasn't anything. Really.
- Pero cómo que **no** fue **nada**? = What do you mean with nothing?
- **No** fue **nada** agradable = It wasn't too nice.

Indefinido + verbo (sin adv 'no' necesariamente):

- **Nadie** lo sabe = No one knows.
- **Nunca** Estuvo Ahí = She never got there.
- **Ninguno** de ellos pensó simplemente en comprarlo = None of them had thought to just go buy it.

No + verbo + Adv. de negación:

- Pero es que a mí **no** me gustan, y a ellos **tampoco** = But I don't like them, and neither do they/doesn't as well.
- **No** espere verla consciente **tampoco** = But don't expect to see her conscious.

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doble_negaci%C3%B3n_(ling%C3%BC%C3%ADstica)